# Which function has the following series representation? x^n/n!!

Tags: sequences-and-series

We know that $\sum_{n=0} ^ \infty \dfrac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$

Which function has the following series representation?

$\sum_{n=0} ^ \infty \dfrac{x^n}{n!!}$

Yes, is a double factorial.

Comment: Another one. Not every power series has a name.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica gives
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!!}=\frac{1}{2} e^{x^2/2}[2+\sqrt{2\pi} ~\text{erf}(x/\sqrt{2})].$$